# Enter key function sometimes works and sometimes doesn't

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a search box which should work with pressing the button and also pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. They both have the same code.
The button works perfectly but when it comes to the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, most of the time it doesn't work and sometimes it suddenly works.

**Here's my code:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function myFunction() {
    $("#search-criteria").keydown(function(event) {
      if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        var txt = $('#search-criteria').val();
        $('.items:contains("' + txt + '")').addClass('searched');
      }
    });
  }

  $('#search').click(function() {
    var txt = $('#search-criteria').val();
    $('.items:contains("' + txt + '")').addClass('searched');
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" id="search-criteria" onkeydown="myFunction()" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
  <input type="button" id="search" value="search" />
</form>
```

Comment: Adding event listeners in event handlers is almost always problematic. In your case you're adding a new listener to `#search-criteria` every time user hits a key on that same element. + what Jacob said in his (no removed) answer, the default action of `ENTER` on a text input element is to submit the form containing that element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding both an `onKeyDown` attribute to your HTML and attaching an event listener. So what's happening is that when your key down occurs, it's calling `myFunction`, which attaches a second event handler for `keydown`. The second time around the enter key behavior might kick in, but because each keydown attaches a new event listener, you might have the logic kick in multiple times.

Choose one approach or the other. Either use the HTML attribute or add the event listener programmatically, but not both.

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" id="search-criteria" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
  <input type="button" id="search" value="search" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#search-criteria").keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      doSearch();
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });

  $('#search').click(function() {
    doSearch();
  });

  function doSearch() {
    var txt = $('#search-criteria').val();
    $('.items:contains("' + txt + '")').addClass('searched');
  }
});
```

(note I also added a `.preventDefault()` to make sure that the default behavior of the enter key doesn't kick in, since it may submit your form)

**Edit**:

Moved duplicated code into its own function.

Comment: This answer isn't the efficient one between the posted here, the DRY concept isn't respected at all here ... Not sure why it was chosen @sara-bagheri.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki However all of them are pointing out the same issue (and it's very true), I rethought & chose Jacob's answer since it has a comprehensive explanation & it's more useful for the people who might have the same question in future.

Comment: Edited to DRY up the code. I didn't include earlier because it wasn't the root problem.

Comment: Yes, _pointing out the same issue_ but the answer is what matters for future readers... However now it looks good after @Jacob update (y) +1

Answer (score 2):

1. Remove the inline-event `onkeydown` you don't need it.
2. You need to use `preventDefault` inside your `myFunction` function.
3. Remove the classes inside your functions to see clearly the new search result.

   ```js
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#search-criteria").keypress(function(event) {
       if (event.which === 13) {
         myFunction();
       }
     });

     //code for the button
     $('#search').click(myFunction);
   });

   var myFunction = function() {
     event.preventDefault();

     var txt = $('#search-criteria').val();

     $('.items').removeClass('searched');
     $('.items:contains("' + txt + '")').addClass('searched');
   }
   ```

   ```css
   .searched {
     background-color: green;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <form>
     <input type="text" id="search-criteria" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
     <input type="button" id="search" value="search" />
   </form>


   <ul>
     <li class="items">Coffee</li>
     <li class="items">Tea</li>
     <li class="items">Milk</li>
     <li class="items">Coffee</li>
     <li class="items">Tea</li>
     <li class="items">Milk</li>
     <li class="items">Coffee</li>
     <li class="items">Tea</li>
     <li class="items">Milk</li>
   </ul>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I made a couple of small changes to the code you posted and it is working well for me as a snippet.

I documented the changes in the code itself.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //code for Enter key
  function myFunction() {
    console.log("myFunction called");

    var txt = $('#search-criteria').val();
    $('.items:contains("' + txt + '")').addClass('searched');
  }

  $("#search-criteria").keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      // Keep the ENTER key from submitting the form.
      event.preventDefault();
      myFunction();
    }
  });


  //code for the button
  $('#search').click(function() {
    var txt = $('#search-criteria').val();
    $('.items:contains("' + txt + '")').addClass('searched');

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <!--
    the `onkeydown` on this can't work, since 'myfunction' isn't in the global space 
    so I removed it.
  -->

  <input type="text" id="search-criteria" name="search" placeholder="Search..">
  <input type="button" id="search" value="search" />
</form>
```